# JAXB JSON force brackets on arrays

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I'm trying to force brackets on lists that contain only one element.

I want something like this:
{"id":"0","industries":[{"id":"0","name":"Technologies"}],"name":"Google Inc."}

But I get:
{"id":"0","industries":{"id":"0","name":"Technologies"},"name":"Google Inc."}

Here is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Company {
 private int id;

 private String name;
 private String description;

 @XMLElement(name="industries")
 private List<Industry> industryList;

    [...]
```

And finally, my JAXB Context Resolver:

```
public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
```

MappedBuilder builder = JSONConfiguration.mapped();
  builder.arrays("industries");
  builder.rootUnwrapping(true);

this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(builder.build(), Company.class);
 }

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help, but I found the answer. You actually need to specify a JAXBContextResolver which specify natural JSON configuration. You need to provide a type list of every container that need to be transform to JSON. In this example, you can see that I specified the GetCompanyResponse that is a container of Company.

```
@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class[] types = { GetCompanyResponse.class };

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(), types);
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        for (Class clazz : types) {
            if (clazz.equals(objectType)) {
                return context;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) provides native JSON-binding support.  It will correctly marshal collections of size 1 wrapped as a JSON array.  Below is a complete example.

**Company**

```
package forum3946102;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company {
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @XmlElement(name = "industries")
    private List<Industry> industryList;
}
```

**Industry**

```
package forum3946102;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Industry {
    private int id;

    private String name;
}
```

**jaxb.properties**

In order to specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum3946102;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Company.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        String jsonString = "{\"id\":\"0\",\"industries\":[{\"id\":\"0\",\"name\":\"Technologies\"}],\"name\":\"Google Inc.\"}";
        StreamSource jsonSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(jsonString));
        Company company = unmarshaller.unmarshal(jsonSource, Company.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        marshaller.marshal(company, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
{"id" : 0, "name" : "Google Inc.", "industries" : [{"id" : 0, "name" : "Technologies"}]}
```

**For More Information**

- [JSON Binding with EclipseLink MOXy - Twitter Example](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html)
- [MOXy as Your JAX-RS JSON Provider - Server Side](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about this, but try removing the `@XMLElement` annotation for **industryList**

I have done stuff the other way around: using jaxb to generate java classes from  xsd schema  files. I've looked at the generated classes with collection fields, and they don't have any specific annotations on them.

Also you may wanna try JSON Lib: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

you could do things like:

```
jsonString = JSONObject.fromObject(pojoObject)
```

which will generate json string that will incorporate e.g. collections of complex types.

You could then send the jsonString using e.g. HttpServletResponse.

I would recommend serializing DTO objects rather than serialize your entity objects.

Answer (score 0):

Drill down JSONObject and swap out an area that needs to be JSONArray. Once created, json **putOpt** will replace old reference object with new.

**Before**
"Investment": {"SubAccount": {
                    "id": "SubAccountId_2_CORP",
                    "AllocPercent": "100.0",
                    "ProductCode": "PC01",
                    "ProductFullName": "Product Full Name"
                }}

**After**
"Investment": {"SubAccount": **[**{
             "id": "SubAccountId_2_CORP",
             "AllocPercent": "100.0",
             "ProductCode": "PC01",
             "ProductFullName": "Product Full Name"
        }**]**}

```
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import org.json.XML;
 private static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
```

.
.
.
.

```
            try {
            org.json.JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(inBatchTrans.getINPUT_MESSAGE()); 

            try {
                JSONArray subAcctArray = xmlJSONObj.getJSONObject("TXLife").getJSONObject("TXLifeRequest").getJSONObject("OLifE").getJSONObject("Holding").getJSONObject("Investment").getJSONArray("SubAccount");
                // Already JsonArray do nothing
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // convert to Array
                JSONObject subAcctObj = xmlJSONObj.getJSONObject("TXLife").getJSONObject("TXLifeRequest").getJSONObject("OLifE").getJSONObject("Holding").getJSONObject("Investment").getJSONObject("SubAccount");
                JSONArray keys = subAcctObj.names();
                JSONArray values = subAcctObj.toJSONArray(keys);

                JSONObject subAccount = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray  subAccountList = new JSONArray();
                int key = keys.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < key; i++) {
                    subAccount.put(keys.get(i).toString(), values.get(i));
                }
                subAccountList.put(0, subAccount);
                xmlJSONObj.getJSONObject("TXLife").getJSONObject("TXLifeRequest").getJSONObject("OLifE").getJSONObject("Holding").getJSONObject("Investment").putOpt("SubAccount", subAccountList);
            }

            String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
            System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
        } catch (org.json.JSONException je) {
            System.out.println(je.toString());
        }
```